# Is it impossible to find the probability of two pairs in a hand of five without combinatorics?

Tags: probability, combinations

I know the conventional solution to this is by counting the number of ways to form two pairs and pick a fifth unrelated card divided by the number of possible ways to pick 5 cards out of a deck, but why can't this problem be solved with basic probability?

I reasoned that the act of picking 5 cards could be represented as picking 5 cards one at a time without replacement

Therefore I thought that

P(1st card) + P(matching rank) + P(3rd card) + P(matching rank) + P(unrelated rank)

= 1/1 * 3/51 * 48/50 * 3/49 * 8/48

Should yield the same result as using combinations to find the probability of drawing 2 pairs, but it yields 12/4165 whereas using combinations yields 198/4165, a much higher probability.

Why? Why is this approach wrong?

Here's how to find the solution using combinations:

$p=\dfrac{{13\choose 3}\cdot {4\choose 2}\cdot {4\choose 2}\cdot 44}{{52\choose 5}}$

Comment: Your first method counts 2H,2D,3S,3C,8H as a different hand from 3S,3C,2D,2H,8H. Also thay final 8/48 should be 44/48.

Answer (score 1):

You calculated the probability that you pick one card, then another card of the same rank of the first, then any card of a different rank, then a card of the same rank as the third, then any unrelated card. That's not the only way you can get two pair. For instance, your first card could be the unrelated card. Or the first and third card could match, rather than the first and second.

To compensate for this undercounting, you need to account for all possible permutations. So that's ${5\choose 2}=10 $  places for one pair, ${3\choose 2}=3$ for the other pair, and then divide by two as to not double count (we should not regard the xyxyz configuration as distinct from the yxyxz). So the correct answer should be 15 times your first answer.

You miscalculated a bit. It should be $$ (3/51)(48/50)(3/49)(44/48)=\frac{66}{20825}.$$ Multiplying by $15$ gives $\frac{198}{4165}.$

Comment: How do you know that the probability of all the other ways of drawing two pairs is the same as the one I calculated?

Comment: @Shisui Symmetry. If we gave the deck an extra shuffle that just permuted the top five cards in some prescribed way before dealing, could that change things?